# Guidance on broadening horizons

Tags: programming-languages

Let me setup my question with some info. I'm not in college yet and strictly a hobby programmer. Probably a little more than 2 years ago I got started programming on mac. I started with very simplistic GUI examples with Cocoa and XCode. Long story short, I learned from the top down, first learning objective-c, then venturing into more "low-level" projects where I became better at basic C and even used a few C++ libraries in my existing projects.

What I'm saying is that I've never really done anything outside of an XCode project and occasional iPhone project. I've implemented lots of stuff, algorithms, math, etc. but all *within* that environment. I look at the world of programming and there is so much out there that's not necessarily a standalone application. It seems to me that the hardest thing is finding out *where* to start; *how* to setup the environment. I guess I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions, projects, tutorials, maybe on setting up environments for different languages on different systems. Web programming, java applets? etc.

On the note of environments, I would be interested in knowing on a more basic level what makes a "development environment." To my basic knowledge, an "environment" combines the language, with the compiler that interprets that language, and contains libraries that provide an API for the language, where the compiled product runs on a certain system. This is my basic concept, but again, I'm here.

Sorry if this question... well... combines too many questions, but any input or guidance is welcome. Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly or if this will help you, but here are my (relative newbie) thoughts and rambling:

I've done Java at uni in two different courses, one where we wrote the code in Notepad and then compiled it in command line, in some dubious DOS application, and then two years later when we worked in NetBeans and while NetBeans was a lot better and easier, I learned a lot and was a lot more careful when writing code after the Notepad experience (especially after waiting for several minutes for a compile only to see a message caused by a silly bug).

If you can choose between IDEs, I would read on different blogs, see what people prefer and why and make a choice. The problem is that most of the time, both at uni and at work, you can't choose and have to go with the teachers/managers choose, and make the best of it.

> It seems to me that the hardest thing is finding out where to start; how to setup the environment.

I think it would be easiest if you found something that you want to do, and then take small steps and get bits done. I work as a desktop app developer and 3 years ago I set up a wordpress blog for a friend and imported posts and comments from a different blogging platform, with minimal knowledge about everything involved. I started with things that were already done by others and learned how to use them and then slowly tried to fill in the gaps - the comments part wasn't done then, so I had to learn about databases, how I could see them and then write the code that inserted in them, etc.

What I'm trying to say is that if you find something to do (and if you don't have ideas for projects, you can find several posts with ideas here, on SO) and then set goals towards doing that, even if you don't finish it, or your studying takes you in areas you hadn't expected, it will all be useful at some point.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions, projects, tutorials, maybe on setting up environments for different languages on different systems. Web programming, java applets? etc.

This is way too broad a question.  If you're doing web programming, you need to set up a web programming environment.  At a minimum, you would need an HTTP server.  You'd probably also need a relational database.  The rest of the web environment would be language dependent.

If you're doing GUI programmng, you would need access to the device or devices (iPhone, Android, etc.) that you want to write programs for.

> To my basic knowledge, an "environment" combines the language, with the compiler that interprets that language, and contains libraries that provide an API for the language, where the compiled product runs on a certain system.

That gets you started, yes. You'd want an integrated development environment to write the code.  Again, you'd probably need a relational or object oriented database.  The rest of the development environment is language dependent.